# How to SELECT from column where type = 1 and SEARCH term?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, select

Trying to write a funny query, don't know if it's possible.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Type = '1' ";
$sql .= "WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$searchq%' or LastName LIKE '%$searchq%'";
```

So selecting all from users from the column with type 1, and the concatenated part is whatever which has been entered in the search box. is this even possible? Or do I have to write up two different querys?
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I hope you have used [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because this looks terrifyingly insecure.

Comment: The above was just posted merely as a quick example...and yup used mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Still not great that you're using the horribly antiquated `mysql_query`. Hope you're planning to migrate to something newer like PDO before support is dropped from PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use parenthesis to organize your `WHERE` statements:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Type = '1' 
    AND (FirstName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR LastName LIKE '%$searchq%')";
```

Comment: Yeah, I read about the parenthesis, tried it but failed. But yeah needed to concatenate it as its inside of a loop. Yup works perfect! Cheers